# Regex combining optional group with conditions

Tags: regex

The following combinations should be covered by this regex:

- test-ds-s**
- test-s**
- test-d**

(** two numbers from 0-9)

My regex looks like this: `^test-(ds-)?[ds]\\d{2,2}$`

But now **test-ds-d**** is also possible, what I dont want. Is there any way to make the **d** only possible, when the optional **ds-** part is not used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
^test-(ds-(?!d))?[ds]\d{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDQWz0/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `test-` - a fixed string
- `(ds-(?!d))?` - an optional capturing group matching `ds-` if not immediately followed with `d`
- `[ds]` - `d` or `s`
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `$` - end of string.